# How to Choose One Entity to Display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, properties, entity-framework-6, viewmodel

I am working on an Auction application where there are multiple "Auction" entity's that have "Categories" and those have "Items". Right now, I have a database that stores these auctions with reference to their respective categories, items etc. However, the problem I have now is that how my site works is that it pulls from the database to display the categories and is pulling them from every auction instead of the "current" Auction.

I have a database first design so I can't add any more properties to my entities. I have thought about using a [NotMapped] property but I wouldn't be able to store that value and use it when pulling from my db because it wouldn't be in the db. ViewModels could work, however that requires a lot of rework and requires that I store a bool for every single auction when really only one Auction can be the "current" action at a time. I was thinking that I could use a radio button, (maybe on the index page?) Where the user could select which Auction is the current one and then the logic I have for displaying my categories would choose to display only the ones from that auction. This would make it simple and easy for a user to change Auctions.

> What is the best way for me to go about doing this so that I can display only the Auction that I want while also not just hardcoding the current auctions name so that it is user friendly.

I believe that others may benefit from this discussion so if there is any way I can improve my question please let me know.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Could I use some kind of ViewData or TempData but the persistent kind to pass the name of the current auction indicated by the radio button to my index of displaying the categories?

Comment: Why don't you show the problematic code? How are you associating a `Category` with an `Auction`?

Comment: how are you currently showing one Auction?

Comment: Right now how I am showing the categories is by looping through var cats = db.Cats.Include(c => c.Auction).OrderBy(c => c.SeqNo); However, all the categories for every auction are in Cats. I could add .Where(c =>c.AuctionId = "id that I want") but I am trying to avoid hardcoding like that

Comment: I think that's what you should be doing, though. Let the user select an auction. Use that auctionId to filter the Categories. Then when they choose a category, use that category id to filter the items. Then they can bid on a specific item.

Comment: That makes sense. How the application works is most likely annually a new auction will come out and this will be the "current" Auction. So I wanted the user to be able to set the current auction and that would persist until the user selects the new auction as the current. How could I accomplish this given my constraints?

Comment: Use maybe a dropdown of the auctions in db.Auctions that only administrators can see and then it updates the categories from there?

Comment: How are you persisting which auction is current? Is it a column in the `Auction` table? Can you do `var categories = Categories.Where(c => c.AuctionId == Auctions.First(a => a.Current == true).Id);`?

Comment: That's the problem is that I currently am not and can not persist which auction is current in my table. Would it be reasonable to sort my auctions by Start Date and then "select" the most recent one to always be the one that is displayed? I was trying to do it differently maybe for testing or for looking at the "old" site for archiving purposes, but that might not be realistic

Comment: You're asking questions we can't answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think what I was trying to accomplish wasn't practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to go ahead and add a property in your table for if the item is active or not and then just query with db.Cats.Where(c =>c.Auction.ActiveInd == true) like Rufus stated.

Also one could use viewModels for a similar situation.

Thank you all.